# AngularJS custom headers request

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic app, and trying to set custom headers for every GET request I do on the app.

This is the CustomHeaderController

```
angular.module('myHeader',[])
.controller('headerCtrl',['customHeader',function(customHeader){
var config = {headers:  {
'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
'Accept': 'text/html;odata=verbose',
"X-Request-from" : "{{vm.data.os}}" }};
$http.get('http://localhost:8100, config); }])
```

At the moment when I inspect the page, I do not get any custom header, just the default one.

Any clues? Appreciate it! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use interceptor in this case with every http request.

[Interceptor Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787417/angular-http-interceptors-configuration)

Comment: cheers mate! And if I want to check for only one request, for example http://lcoalhost:8100 ? Do I still have to use interceptors? Or I could use the code I have

Comment: Ideally in application there will be like as many as HTTP request, so its good habit to use intercepter.

Comment: Cheers! @Parvin Erande